# Could this planetary superalignment happen?

Tags: orbital-motion, planets, solar-system, celestial-mechanics

Here's the 'superalignment' I'm referring to:

[image: Planetary Superalignment]

We've all heard the stories about 'mystical planetary alignments' that will increase/decrease the effective surface gravity experienced on Earth ([one debunked here on snopes](http://www.snopes.com/humor/iftrue/zerogday.asp)), sometimes referred to as 'Zero G Day'.

What I'm wondering is: what would be the maximum possible effect on a given weight (ratio of 'normal' weight to 'alignment' weight)?

1. Noon at a new moon, Venus and Mercury between the Earth and the Sun, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus and Neptune across the sun in roughly a straight line (maximum lightness).
2. Midnight during the same alignment (maximum heaviness - almost the same ratio, but 2 Earth radii further away from the planets and sun).

Also, how often (if ever) could this happen?

### EDIT

I have calculated the resulting effects of this 'superalignment':

[image: Planetary Superalignment Calculator]

The result is that with the planets and our moon aligned as much as they can be to have their forces be additive, their gravity culminates in a $\pm0.06\%$ difference. Since I weigh 90kg, I would weigh 89.94 kg at noon and 90.05 kg at midnight.

Now, the last part of this question remains - would this superalignment, or something approximating this superalignment, ever occur, and if so would it be on a repetition and how often?

Comment: You can calculate this yourself. Use Newton's formula for the gravitational force and plug in some numbers for the minimum distances between the planets and the moon. You will find that the effects are very small. Having said that, the long term dynamics of the solar system depends very delicately on these small forces adding up resonantly over millions and hundreds of millions of years. The cumulative effects are large and it is predicted that the solar system is most likely unstable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_of_the_Solar_System

Comment: I'm not after minimum distance of each planet summed; I'm looking for maximum cumulative gravitational effects (Jupiter, for example, would be across the Sun). Also, how would it be possible to answer how often (if ever) said alignment with as much error margin is necessary would occur?

Comment: The Earth is falling freely around the sun, which doesn't change for any constellation of planets. The force of gravity depends on the square of the distance, though and Jupiter's distance varies from 588 to 968 million km. If you plug the ratio of that in, the planet's gravity on Earth varies by a factor of up to 2.7. I think it would be interesting for you to explore the total force as a function of time with a simple model using a first order circular orbit model (the errors will be small). Have fun!

Comment: I never said it did? I'm looking for an answer to $\frac {F_g - F_{moon} - F_{Venus} - F_{Mercury} - F_{Sun} - F_{Mars} - F_{Jupiter} - F_{Saturn} - F_{Uranus}- F_{Neptune}} {F_g}$ when they are in a particular collinear arrangement such that they are all constructive, and also if this arrangement is possible and if so how often it will happen / how soon until the next one, and I was assuming within a suitable margin of error this would happen at least once before the solar system became unstable.

Comment: So what stops you from calculating it yourself? A simple Excel spreadsheet could tell you a good approximation to the max. and there are plenty of digital orreries available to calculate the future constellations.

Comment: The calculation component could have been done before, in which case a link would suffice and save a deal of time, and I'm unaware of where I can find 'time to specified alignment'. What stops you from answering it? This is a question AND ANSWER site, after all.

Comment: This site has an "insufficient effort" rule. It's not here to do your google searches for you.

Comment: With the latest edit to this question, making it about whether the alignment could happen at all, it's a perfectly good question, but the stuff about how large the gravitational effect would be is now pretty irrelevant. So I'd suggest taking that out entirely.

Comment: The time between such alignments is on the same order of magnitude as the least common multiple of all the orbital periods, each rounded to some integer multiple of a fundamental unit, e.g. in days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/2427/

Comment: No @lionelbrits, it is not a duplicate. That question is asking about simple collinearity of all 8 planets; I'm asking about a specific form of collinearity where the gravitational forces are maximally additive.

Comment: @DavidZ, I'd prefer not to remove it as the spirit of the initial question was about both magnitude/effects and possibility/timing; I was just pushed into answering the first part myself. They belong together in my opinion, jointly explaining superalignment.

Comment: Well, it's your question, but I really think including the extra material makes your question substantially more confusing.

Comment: I'm only interested in said planetary alignments to demonstrate a maximal upper bound on planetary alignment effects (and likelihood/frequency) to provide a response to these 'zero-g day' posts. I want this to contain a full response for anyone googling 'zero g days' or gravitation effects of planetary alignments, thus the information is important (to me).

Comment: Hi Ehryk. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic I have read it, and I disagree that it applies to this question. I'd be happy to discuss in chat.

Answer (score 3):

[SciShow covered this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPLnh0Mu95k) and their sources are in the video description.  It probably can't happen, but it depends on your tolerances.

Planetary alignments have a "quality" which is how far apart in the sky the planets are allowed to be and still considered in "alignment".  All planets lined up in a nice straight line from the Earth to the Sun?  Almost impossible due to the planets' movement above and below the plane of the ecliptic.  How about lining up in just two dimensions?  Also almost impossible, there are too many moving parts.

This [source from the National Solar Observatory](https://web.archive.org/web/20051214013307/http://www.sunspot.noao.edu/PR/alignment.html) calculated the next time the planets will be aligned within 30 degrees is March 20, 2673 and the last time was Jan 1, 1665.  There's details in the article.

As for the effect on gravity, it will be inconsequential compared to the pull of the Moon and Jupiter.  [Phil Plait did the math](http://www.badastronomy.com/bad/misc/planets.html) (so did [NASA, but only for tides](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2000/ast30mar_1m/)) and Jupiter only has 1% the gravitational influence as the Moon with the rest of the planets rapidly falling off into inconsequential amounts.  The position of the Moon and Jupiter will swamp any other gravitational considerations.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll review the details when I get a chance. I'm beginning to realize that what I'm after is something different than the typical definition of planetary alignment, and includes a solar and lunar alignment _in the same gravitational direction_, in other words Mars through Neptune are across the Sun.

Comment: @Ehryk The odds won't be very different.  You want 8 orbital bodies to be in certain positions in their orbits, it doesn't matter much what those positions are unless they're in orbital resonance (only a problem with Pluto and Neptune).  Due to the overwhelming gravitational influence of Jupiter and the Moon, the position of the other planets will have no appreciable effect.

Comment: I want 8 planets, a star, and the Earth's moon to be in alignment. 10 bodies.

Comment: @Ehryk With a period of 28 days, less than a third of the next fastest, Mercury, the Moon doesn't make much difference.  The Sun doesn't count, it's stationary relative to everything else.

Comment: The sun does count. Many 'planetary alignments' are based on aligning 'in the sky', and being collinear without solar inclusion. Here's an example of such an alignment: http://modernsurvivalblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/planetary-alignment.jpg

Comment: @Ehryk Ahh, I see.